# How to get the mysql column/field value in PHP without specifying each field?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to PHP and MySQL so please bear with me...

I am trying to get the field values of a mysql table using a `for loop`. I know to how to get it by using `mysql_fetch_array`  but the thing is I have to specify each field. I want to do it by just getting the number of fields and use a loop to get the values. I also tried `mysql_fetch_field` but I can't find any functions that return the value.

Here is the list of `mysql_fetch_field` return values:

- name - column name
- table - name of the table the column belongs to
- max_length - maximum length of the column
- not_null - 1 if the column cannot be NULL
- primary_key - 1 if the column is a primary key
- unique_key - 1 if the column is a unique key
- multiple_key - 1 if the column is a non-unique key
- numeric - 1 if the column is numeric
- blob - 1 if the column is a BLOB
- type - the type of the column
- unsigned - 1 if the column is unsigned
- zerofill - 1 if the column is zero-filled

I also tried reading about `mysql_result` but it seems that you have to specify the field.

> **mysql_result [field]**
>
> The name or offset of the field being retrieved.
>
> It can be the field's offset, the field's name, or the field's table dot field name  (tablename.fieldname). If the column name has been aliased ('select foo as bar from...'), use the alias instead of the column name. If undefined, the first field is retrieved.

Here is my code fragment:

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <?php
   for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); ++$i) echo  "<th>" . mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>"  ;
  ?>
 </tr>
 <?php 
  for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); ++$i) {  
   echo "<tr>";
   for ($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_fields($result); ++$j) {
    echo "<td>" . // this is where I want to put the function . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
  }
 ?>
</table>
```

Pls help...

Comment: you can do this with out a loop by querying the schema table(s) Chapter 18. INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: You can use $j in your example code as field offset for mysql_result().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function I made which returns all the results from the SQL into an array.

```
<?php
function getResultRows($result)
{
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 1=1';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = getResultRows($result);
print_r($rows);
?>

array(
    [0]array(
        [0]id => 0
        [1]name => blah
    )
    [1]array(
        [0]id => 5
        [1]name => test
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, but is not so efficient, when working with large result sets, as the full result set is loaded into memory. I'd rather implement an iterator which internally holds the resource return by mysql_query and with every call of next() fetching the next row with mysql_fetch_array and releasing the previous.